# How to add sessionToken query parameter for each request?

Tags: swagger, openapi

To use the API, the user need to authenticate ,  a SESSIONID cookie is added to his browser  which will be used for the requests + a sessionToken query parameter.

How can I tell Swagger that for each request a sessionToken query parameter is needed ? Can I add a global query parameter ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to define global parameters in OpenAPI?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19590197/113116)

Comment: Yes,it's a duplicate. I didn't see your answer on the other question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 openapi: 3.0.0

# 1) Define the key name and location
components:
  securitySchemes:
    ApiKeyAuth:        # arbitrary name for the security scheme
      type: apiKey
      in: query       # can be "header", "query" or "cookie"
      name: sessionToken  # name of the header, query parameter or cookie
# 2) Apply the API key globally to all operations
security:
  - ApiKeyAuth: []     # use the same name as under securitySchemes
```

https://swagger.io/docs/specification/authentication/api-keys/