# OpenApi/NelmioAPiDoc: How to add a parameter for every defined route?

Tags: php, symfony, swagger, openapi, nelmioapidocbundle

I have a header param which should be used for every route. But I don't want to add the annotation for this param in every Controller.
I tried different things but it's not possible to add it to an interface or to a class which will be exteneded by every controller. Is there a possibility to make it global?
This is the param I want to set:

```
/**
 * @OA\Parameter(
 *     name="x-locale",
 *     in="header",
 *     description="Locale for siteaccess matching",
 *     )
 */
```

Comment: Did you find something helpful to achieve that ?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the [How to define global parameters in OpenAPI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19590197/how-to-define-global-parameters-in-openapi) it is pretty creepy. Something like this:

```
nelmio_api_doc:
    documentation:
        components:
            securitySchemes:
                # ...
                Locale:
                    type: apiKey
                    in: header
                    name: Accept-language
                    description: "Examples:<br>en<br>en-US"
```