# OpenApiSpec (swagger) reference to common request headers in each path?

Tags: spring-boot, yaml, swagger, openapi, openapi-generator

In a openapi 3.0.0 yaml file, is it possible to reference a list of common request headers that are used in each call rather than specifying them again and again on each call?

```
/some-path:
  get:
    summary: "sample1"
    operationId: doWork
    description: 'description of do work'
    parameters:
      ...
      - in: header
        name: Authorization
        schema: 
          type: string
        required: true
      - in: header
        name: Consumer-Key
        schema: 
          type: string
        required: true
      - in: header
        name: Correlation-Id
        schema:
          type: string
          format: uuid
        required: true

/some-other-path:
  get:
    summary: "sample2"
    operationId: doOtherWork
    description: 'description of do other work'
    parameters:
      ...
      - in: header
        name: Authorization
        schema: 
          type: string
        required: true
      - in: header
        name: Consumer-Key
        schema: 
          type: string
        required: true
      - in: header
        name: Correlation-Id
        schema:
          type: string
          format: uuid
        required: true
```

i tried duplicating it.......and it works......but it is ugly as hell.

Comment: Define the headers at the `components` section once and reference it using `$ref` notation.

Comment: Note that the `Authorization` header MUST be defined as a security scheme instead of a parameter, as explained in the [linked Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44249613/113116).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may not be the answer you want.
With version 3.0.3, we do something like the following:

```
openapi: 3.0.3

paths:
  /some-path:
    get:
      summary: "sample1"
      operationId: doWork
      description: 'description of do work'
      parameters:
        ...
        - in: header
          name: Authorization
          schema: 
            type: string
          required: true
        - in: header
          name: Consumer-Key
          schema: 
            type: string
          required: true
        - $ref: '#/components/parameters/__common__correlationId_header'

components:
  parameters:
    __common__correlationId_header:
      in: header
      name: Correlation-Id
      description: common correlation id.
      required: true
      schema:
        type: string
        format: uuid
```

Comment: thank you.  i was looking for a single line for the collection but ill take this route any day.  works well!  thanks so much!