# OpenAPI Security Scheme: What is 'type' used for in Cookie auth?

Tags: cookies, swagger, openapi

OpenAPI allows you to specify various [security schemes](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/authentication/) for authentication and authorization: basic auth, OAuth 2.0, etc. Among them is the simple scheme of having a token or key send in a specific cookie header field: [Cookie Authentication](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/authentication/cookie-authentication/).

A cookie auth scheme can look like this according to the example on the Swagger page:

```
components:
  securitySchemes:
    cookieAuth:         # arbitrary name for the security scheme
      type: apiKey
      in: cookie
      name: JSESSIONID  # cookie name
```

I'm wondering about the used **type** attribute. According to the [latest OAS 3.0.2 spec](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/3.0.2.md#securitySchemeObject) the type attribute is

- a string
- required
- valid values are `apiKey`, `http`, `oauth2`, `openIdConnect`.

But can someone actually let me know what these different types actually mean? Is the idea here to just reuse the `apiKey` type, even if the key/token in question is no an actual API key?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is the idea here to just reuse the `apiKey` type... ?

Yes.

The term ["API key"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1453073/113116) is pretty generic and refers to "some kind of a token that identifies the consumer" - this includes authentication cookies.